# U-shaped magnet geometry in three.js

Tags: three.js

I want to create a "U" shaped magnet in three.js. So can I use TubeGeometry for that?

So if this is the code for creating a 3D sin curve. How can I make it as "U" shaped Magnet?

```
    var CustomSinCurve = THREE.Curve.create(

        function ( scale ) { //custom curve constructor

        this.scale = ( scale === undefined ) ? 1 : scale;

                       },

        function ( t ) { //getPoint: t is between 0-1

        var tx = t * 3 - 1.5;
        var ty = Math.sin( 2 * Math.PI * t );
        var tz = 0;

        return new THREE.Vector3( tx, ty, tz ).multiplyScalar(this.scale);

       }

   );

       var path = new CustomSinCurve( 10 );
       var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( path, 20, 2, 8, false );
       var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
       var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
       scene.add( mesh );
```

Comment: This sounds like a request for freelancing work...

Comment: I didn't understand what you are talking about?

Comment: I mean that there is not a simple answer to this question. The only answer would be for someone to do all the work for you.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that.As I don't know that just simply asked it assuming that it would be simple.

Comment: @Naren mark answers as accepted, if they solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

If the shape of the magnet's profile is not critical (rectangle instead of circle), then you can use `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry()`:

[image]

```
var path = new THREE.Shape(); // create a U-shape with its parts
path.moveTo(-1, 1);
path.absarc(0, 0, 1, Math.PI, Math.PI * 2);
path.lineTo(1, 1);
path.lineTo(.8, 1);
path.absarc(0, 0, .8, Math.PI * 2, Math.PI, true);
path.lineTo(-.8,1);
path.lineTo(-1, 1);

var extOpt = { // options of extrusion
    curveSegments: 15,
    steps: 1,
    amount: .2,
    bevelEnabled: false
}

var uGeom = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(path, extOpt); // create a geometry
uGeom.center(); // center the geometry
var average = new THREE.Vector3(); // this variable for re-use
uGeom.faces.forEach(function(face){
  average.addVectors(uGeom.vertices[face.a], uGeom.vertices[face.b]).add(uGeom.vertices[face.c]).divideScalar(3); // find the average vector of a face
  face.color.setHex(average.x > 0 ? 0xFF0000 : 0x0000FF); // set color of faces, depends on x-coortinate of the average vector
});

var uMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors }); // we'll use face colors

var u = new THREE.Mesh(uGeom, uMat);
scene.add(u);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/z0spcvf1/) example